# Let $A,B,X$ be sets such that $A \cup B = X$ and $A \cap B= \phi$. Show that, $A = X\setminus B$ and $B=X\setminus A$. (Tao's Analysis I)

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I would like someone to verify my proof. If there's a better/cleaner way to do it, I'd really love to know.

> Let $A,B,X$ be sets such that $A \cup B = X$ and $A \cap B= \phi$. Show that, $A = X\setminus B$ and $B=X \setminus A$.

***Proof.*** (My attempt).

**Claim.** $A = X \setminus B.$

($\Rightarrow$ direction).

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element in the set $A$.

$\begin{align}
&x \in A \\
\text{So, } & x \in (A \cup B) \\
\therefore \text{ } & x \in X \\
\therefore \text{ } & (x \in B) \lor (x \in X \setminus B) \\
& \text{If x is in B, then x belongs to both A and B. This is a}\\ 
& \text{contradiction as the intersection is an empty set.}\\
\implies & (x \in X \setminus B)\\
\therefore \text{ } & A \subseteq (X \setminus B)
\end{align}$

($\Leftarrow$ direction).

Let $y$ be an arbitrary element in the set $X \setminus B$. Therefore, $y \in (A \cup B)$. Which means that $(y \in A) \lor (y \in B)$. But, $y \notin B$ (because $y$ belongs to $X \setminus B)$. Therefore, $y \in A$.

This closes the proof.

Comment: Looks fine to me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof works fine. I don't know if Tao does "set algebra" or not, otherwise an alternative:

Note that $A \cap B=\emptyset$ implies $A \subseteq B^\complement$ and so $A \cap B^\complement = A$. Then

$$(X \setminus B) = X \cap B^\complement = (A \cup B)\cap B^\complement = (A \cap B^\complement) \cup (B \cap B^\complement) = A \cup \emptyset = A$$

And similarly for the other equality.